# JPA: Mapping crossed OneToOne and ManyToOne relations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, which we'll call A and B. B always has A as a parent with a ManyToOne relation.
However, I need A to have a OneToOne relation with the latest record inserted in table B.
This is because I need to save multiple versions of B but 99% of the time will only need to use the most recent one.

This looks something like this:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;

    /* Properties
       ...
    */

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private B latest;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;

    /* Properties
       ...
    */

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date lastModified;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private A parent;
}
```

Now, the issue at hand is that I cannot seem to persist these entities as one always appears to be transient:

- A cannot be persisted because `latest` references B, yet B is not persisted.
- B cannot be persisted because `parent` references A, yet A is not persisted.

Attempting to do so results in:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : B.parent -> A

I tried wrapping the code responsible for persisiting them in a `@Transactional` method but the same happens:

```java
@Transactional
public void saveAB(A parent, B child) {
    parent.setLatest(child);
    child.setParent(parent);
    Arepository.save(parent);
    Brepository.save(child);
}
```

I also thought of disregarding the OneToOne relation from A to B, instead having `latest` as a transient `@Formula` field which would query B to take the most recent record. However, `@Formula` seems to be limited to primitives, not full entities.

What would be the proper way to do this with JPA? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Just have a look at this https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/ -> Relationships

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK Thank you. I actually found an example for my exact scenario in "Advanced mapping techniques": https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-the-latest-child-of-a-parent-entity-using-hibernate-joinformula/
The original StackOverflow question didn't get many upvotes so I guess I didn't stumble into it naturally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to apply @JoinFormula as explained [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-the-latest-child-of-a-parent-entity-using-hibernate-joinformula/).

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;

    /* Properties
       ...
    */

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT b.id FROM b " +
            "WHERE b.id = id ORDER BY b.lastModified DESC LIMIT 1)")
    private B latest;
}
```

Then on B:

```
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private A parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `A` and `B` depend on each other they should probably be considered a single [aggregate](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) with `A` being the aggregate root.

This means you'd have only an `ARepository` and also `CascadeType.ALL` on the relationships.